# How do I get `gasLimit` in web3?

Tags: web3js, gas-limit, genesis

I am running in a private ethereum network which I `init` with a `genesis.json` file that contains

`"gasLimit": "31415926"`

Now I am wondering how I can read that via web3, any suggestions? (I want to make sure the limit is set correctly).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Asking for the last block mined, it will return the gasLimit of the block
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetblock

```
var block = web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
console.log("gasLimit: " + block.gasLimit);
```

---

Note for web3 v1.x: `getBlock` is an async function and you have to use await to get the expected result

```
var block = await web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
console.log("gasLimit: " + block.gasLimit);
```

Comment: The gas limit I am getting from this is absurdly high (For an individual transaction), but this is the gas limit for the whole block though, correct? If so, then to estimate the gas I should use on an individual transaction, do I just divide by the number of transactions in said block? Or is it safe to just always use the gasLimit minimum of 21000?

Comment: This is giving me 'undefined', maybe there is an upgrade?

Comment: @rsc05 You need to wait the function returns: await block.gasLimit

Answer (score 3):

Here is the exact answer:

```
var block = await web3js.eth.getBlock("latest");
var gasLimit = block.gasLimit/block.transactions.length;
```

Comment: The block gasLimit total is always about 30000000, but the number of transactions is variable in each block. Sometimes 1, sometimes 6..... the gasLimit is so different in each case if I take your division by the trx length

Comment: For python code, it should be ```gas_limit = int(latest_block.gasLimit / (1 if len(latest_block.transactions) == 0 else len(latest_block.transactions)))```

Comment: This is giving me 'undefined', maybe there is an upgrade?